# Formula for Jacobian determinant

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be open and $f\in C^1(U;\mathbb{R}^2)$. We also have $f(x_0)=y_0$. Suppose that $\overline{B}^2_\delta (x_0) \subset U$, so $\partial \overline{B}^2_\delta (x_0) = (\delta \cos(t),\delta \sin(t))+x_0$, when $t\in [0,2\pi]$. Now we set $\varphi(t)-x_0=(\delta \cos(t),\delta \sin(t))$.

How to derive the following

$$(f(\varphi(t))-y_0))\times (f(\varphi(t))-y_0)'=[\det f'(x_0)+o(|\delta|)](\varphi(t)-x_0)\times (\varphi(t)-x_0)', \space \space as  \space \space \delta \rightarrow 0,$$

where $a\times b=(0,0,a_1b_2-a_2b_1).$

---

I do understand that $(\varphi(t)-x_0)\times (\varphi(t)-x_0)'=(0,0,1)$, but I don't understand why $(f(\varphi(t))-y_0))\times (f(\varphi(t))-y_0)' \rightarrow  (0,0,\det f'(x_0))$, as $\delta \rightarrow 0$. I guess there is something simple that I don't see.

Comment: Working in 2 dimensions perhaps more natural to define $(a,c)\times(b,d)=ad-bc$ (a number)?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^2$. We need to work in $\mathbb{R}^3$ since the cross product indicates the orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (Taylor on the first part, derivative on the second and inserting $0=(x_0)'$): $$ (f(\phi(t))-y_0)\times (f(\phi(t))-y_0)'= 
 ((f'(x_0)+o(\delta))(\phi(t)-x_0)) \times (f'(x_0)(\phi(t)-x_0)')= [\det(f'(x_0))+o(\delta)] (\phi(t)-x_0)\times (\phi(t)-x_0)'$$
(using $\det AB=\det A \det B$ on two by two matrices [the last component of the cross product)

Comment: Are you using some algebraic property of cross product with matrices and vectors in that last step? That conclusion gives me hard time.

Comment: Yes, given two vectors with vanishing third component we have: $(a,c,0)\times (b,d,0)=(0,0,\det (A))$ where $A=(a \ b; c\  d)$. And then $\det(f'(x_0) A)=\det(f'(x_0) \det(A)$. Hope that clairifies?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your answers!